# How to install a portable Tex Live in windows?

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I want to install a portable Tex Live in windows 10. But after searching online I just get this from [the Tex Live guide](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable).

> The -portable installer option (or V command in the text installer or corresponding GUI option) creates a completely self-contained TEX Live installation under a common root and forgoes system integration. You can create such an installation directly on a USB stick, or copy it to a USB stick afterwards.
>
> To run TEX using this portable installation, you need to add the appropriate binary directory to the search path during your terminal session, as usual.
>
> On Windows, you can double-click tl-tray-menu at the root of the installation and create a temporary ‘tray menu’ offering a choice of a few common tasks, as shown in this [screenshot](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-common/tray-menu.png).
>
> The ‘More…’ entry explains how you can customize this menu.

Any more instructions in detail? What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html
2. Select custom install in the installer
   [image]
3. Toggle portable edition (highlighted in red)
   [image]
4. Change main TeX directory to your USB drive (highlighted in red)
   [image]
5. Click install and wait
   [image]

Comment: On current installer there is no option for `Custom Install`. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: Oh... You need to go Simple Install > Install and THEN  you have a GUI appearing with a range of different options, including portable installation.

Comment: @NickRiches How to modify the path to suit for texworks in USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

As of Mar 2022 the GUI option is no longer available.

Use the following method as described in [The TeX Live Guide—2022 - 4.2 Portable (USB) installations](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-420004.2).

"The -portable installer option (or V command in the text installer or corresponding GUI option) creates a completely self-contained TeX Live installation under a common root and forgoes system integration. You can create such an installation directly on a USB stick, or copy it to a USB stick afterwards."