# Company policy won't let me install LaTeX. Is there a way to create a standalone .exe?

Tags: standalone

My company has very restrictive IT policies. I am not allowed to install LaTeX and the company rules won't let IT install anything that doesn't appear on their list of safe software. I think I see a safe and legal workaround though. I have an application for viewing videos that can produce standalone executables. These standalone executables allow someone without admin rights to use a limited version of the video software just by placing the .exe file on their computer and opening it. 
Has anyone created something similiar for LaTeX?
Does anyone have any ideas for a good workaround? (Safe and legal)

Comment: Why don't you just use overleaf.com?

Comment: https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable

Comment: daleif, I've seen that site. Looks good but companies who are concerned with data leaks and other proprietary issues cannot use it.

Comment: You may be correct. That looks like it might work. I will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

As Skillmon referenced in his comment you could simply use a portable installation of LaTeX.

I'm not sure about MikTeX, but here's a SO question about creating a portable TeXLive installation: [How to install a portable Tex Live in windows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381094/how-to-install-a-portable-tex-live-in-windows)

I believe that you could also do that portable installation in your home directory instead of a USB drive.