# LaTeX Workshop extension using portable LaTeX environment

Tags: latex-workshop, portable

I am currently setting up a portable LaTeX environment (TeX Live) with VisualStudio Code and the LaTeX Workshop extension as the editor. **How do I specify in the LaTeX Workshop settings the path to the LaTeX environment?**

This is for Windows. Changing the environment variable on every computer used is not desirable. I also couldn't find something in the settings of the LaTeX Workshop.

Comment: Assume you already [install portable TeX live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381094/how-to-install-a-portable-tex-live-in-windows), I believe you can just tweak the `command` argument in the configuration or something https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478865/vs-code-latex-workshop-custom-recipes-file-location. Although I haven't tested

Comment: Or [visual studio code - How can I get VSCode's LaTeX Workshop to find the right installation of TeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526320/how-can-i-get-vscodes-latex-workshop-to-find-the-right-installation-of-tex) or [pdftex - How can I get VS Code LaTeX Workshop to choose the correct Latex distribution? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573995/how-can-i-get-vs-code-latex-workshop-to-choose-the-correct-latex-distribution).

Comment: Check the official documentation here, it says basically that on Windows with Tex Live the LaTeX workshop should be able to detect automatically the path: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Install

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have installed the portable TeX live. LaTeX workshop does indeed recognizes the path to the LaTeX environment, but it's not the portable installed version (in the log file is the path to the locally installed LaTeX). When the path variable is removed it's not compiling anymore. Tweaking the `command` argumend works to some extend. But an error occoures and the `glossary` lists have just a text saying that the document is incompleate.

Comment: The result:
`[Builder] Recipe returns with error code 12/null on PID 11792.
[Builder] Does the executable exist? $PATH: undefined
[Builder] Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,437)
...VN\PJE Repo\LaTeX\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe "c:\SVN\PJE Repo\LaTeX\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf -outdir=%TEMPDIR% "c:/Documentation/Projekt/Main"
`

Comment: I have tried to set the `PATH` by using 

`"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
  "PATH": "C:/texlive/2023/bin/windows"
}` in the workspace definition. But it didn't work.